# how to add drag functionality to chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

This is a general question, but how can you add the drag feature to a custom chrome extension.

I'm building a custom chrome ext. but I would like the user to drag it around; currently it's fixed at the right corner.

I would like it to be similar to "Moat" extension (if you're familiar w/ it).  Here is a screenshot of this ext. and [URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moat-extension/eejdpcjcnjbndalmijmikijcjiehfgkd?hl=en).

[image]

Is it simply adding Jquery UI, or do i need to do something special?

I tried to set the width and height 100% to the `body` element, so it would take the whole page and add a `div` inside the `body`, which is the ext, and set a `z-index` to 1, but this approach is not working out. The body width and height is not expanding, and the extension is still fixed at the top right hand corner.

I tried to inspect the element and see if I can find a way to 'detach' from that corner but had no luck with it.

Has anybody had experience with chrome extension and adding a drag feature?  Again, this is a general question. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: You want the dialog box, which is part of the jQuery UI.  See http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/.  You can put whatever HTML you like inside the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You actually could use jQuery UI in a couple of different ways.  Of course, the Dialog Widget is great, but if you only want to drag things around the screen, you can use [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).  You will find a working example at the link.

Once you add the jQuery UI, it is simply one line:

```
$('#yourSelectionID').draggable();
```

For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The above code was taken from the link above.  Please note to include jQuery.js and the jQuery-ui.js files to make this work.